# WordPress Version 5.8.1, CiviCRM 5.18 plugin installed, but DB upgrade fails from civi 5.17.5 -> 5.18

Tags: upgrade, database

I saved a backup and I can revert, but I'd like to go forward with this upgrade. Can anyone please tell me how to fix this? Thanks in advance.

I am upgrading from 5.17.5 (the last patch of 5.17) to 5.18

---

[Error: Remove Index on domain_id that might have been randomly added in the same format as FK]
Error Field Error Value
Type    DB_Error
Code    -1
Message DB Error: unknown error
Mode    16
UserInfo    DROP INDEX FK_civicrm_dashboard_domain_id ON civicrm_dashboard [nativecode=1553 ** Cannot drop index 'FK_civicrm_dashboard_domain_id': needed in a foreign key constraint]
DebugInfo   DROP INDEX FK_civicrm_dashboard_domain_id ON civicrm_dashboard [nativecode=1553 ** Cannot drop index 'FK_civicrm_dashboard_domain_id': needed in a foreign key constraint]
PEAR_Exception: DB Error: unknown error in /home/catastrophic/www/civi/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src/PEAR.php on line 922

- DB_Error: DB Error: unknown error in unknown on line unknown
  Exception trace

Answer (score 0):

This is resolved. For anyone else who runs into this stuff, the answer is to check the logs and read the error message and attempt to make the change to the DB manually. Most of the time, it will just be one issue that can be resolved by manually changing the item, then rerunning the civi database upgrade.